# How to Un-register ( remove ) service worker from a Django login and admin pages?

Tags: javascript, django, web-applications, service-worker, django-login

I had developed an application using Django and implemented service worker on it. but when I redirect to the login and admin page, I want to remove the service worker.

[Service worker](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/service-workers)

Service worker registration process:

### url.py

```
url(r'^sw(.*.js)$' , 'project.views.sw_js', name='sw_js'),
```

### view.py

```
def sw_js(request, js):
template = get_template('sw.js')
html = template.render()
return HttpResponse(html, content_type="application/x-javascript")
```

Comment: What is a service worker? How did you register it? Where is it registered? Why don't you show some code?

Comment: @DanielRoseman: Sorry, Code added pls check.

Answer (score 0):

Use [django decorators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/decorators/)

```
# decorators.py
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.http import Http404

def service_worker(function):
  def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.path.startswith(reverse('admin:index')) or request.path.startswith(reverse('django.contrib.auth.views.login')):
             raise Http404
        else:
            return function(request, *args, **kwargs)


  wrap.__doc__=function.__doc__
  wrap.__name__=function.__name__
  return wrap


url(r'^sw(.*.js)$' , 'project.views.sw_js', name='sw_js'),

@service_worker
def sw_js(request, js):
    template = get_template('sw.js')
    html = template.render()
    return HttpResponse(html, content_type="application/x-javascript")
```

Comment: still, the sw.js file running while opening the user login page.

Comment: Can you paste the admin and login URLs?

Comment: >> Login URL - http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/admin/login/?next=/en/admin/
>> Admin URL -  http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/admin/